# Alternative to using an egg

Tags: food, substitute-tool, eggs

What else can be used as a substitute to an egg?

**Example**: If I was going to bake a cake and one of the ingredients is to use 1 egg, what can be used if I don't have any eggs?

Comment: if you're using a cake mix, check the box for a "low fat" version that typically omits the eggs entirely

Comment: Thanks. I could do that as well, but just in case I don't want to go the "low fat" way its good to know what else can be used in substitute. In my opinion, certain foods have a different taste when they're low fat. @KateGregory

Comment: Sounds like a http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: Oh wow, didnt know there was a cooking site!! Thanks!! @kenorb

Comment: Common ingredient substitutions are such a common and well-documented part of [cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), they are easily referenced in any number of places, so I'm going to close this as *not a hack.* Technically it is, maybe; but if you feel strongly about it, bring it up in meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finely ground flax** makes an excellent binder; however, it has a nutty flavor that's best reserved for whole-grain baked goods and pancakes/Cakes(in your case).

**Baking Soda and Vinegar**
This is a decent egg substitute for fluffier baked goods.

Hold onto your pants for this one,

**BANANAS**
Different sources recommend anywhere from 1/2 to 1 mashed banana as a replacement for 1 egg.

Comment: ... I'm going to go make banana chocolate chip cookies now. That sounds delicious.